# datePicker is not showing on desired place

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uidatepicker

i have created my custom datepicker view and added UIdatePicker and two buttons in it.
both buttons are on the right place as desired but date picker is not showing on its right place

[image]

in image Red area is datepicker

here is my code for datepicker:

```
   @objc func datePicker(){

    //DatepickerView
    self.datePickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: Int(SCREEN_HEIGHT-280), width: Int(SCREEN_WIDTH-10), height: 276)
    self.datePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.datePickerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    self.datePickerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.datePickerView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.datePickerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;

    doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    doneBtn.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    doneBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 80, height: 50)
    doneBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    doneBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black        
   doneBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 
   16.0)
    doneBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
    doneBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    doneBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    doneBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1

    cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(cancelClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cancelBtn.setTitle("Cancel",for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: SCREEN_WIDTH-110, y: 10, width: 80, height: 50)
    cancelBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    cancelBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 16.0)
    cancelBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
    cancelBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1

    // DatePicker    
    self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(SCREEN_WIDTH-20), height: 200))
    self.datePicker?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.datePicker?.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    self.datePicker?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    datePicker.center = view.center

        datePickerView.addSubview(datePicker)
        datePickerView.addSubview(doneBtn)
        datePickerView.addSubview(cancelBtn)

        self.view.addSubview(datePickerView)
        datePickerView.isHidden = true;
}
```

i have tried more than 10 answers in stackoverflow, but did not worked for me.

Any idea why it is not appearing on right place

Comment: Where have you defined `SCREEN_HEIGHT` ?

Comment: No need to set frame for datepicker. Just Add as input view

Comment: in Constant File
let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi Is it because you want to add done and cancel button ?

Comment: That link does not worked for me,
i have to put dynamic height

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi Dynamic height for picker?

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi your 'datePicker' starts from y=0, it should be from 70, because your button ends at 60. and comment ' datePicker.center = view.center' and check again

Comment: @PiyushRathi for testing screen i put this height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly you are trying to achieve ?

According to your code :

```
// DatePicker    
self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(SCREEN_WIDTH-20), height: 200))
self.datePicker?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.datePicker?.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
self.datePicker?.layer.masksToBounds = true
datePicker.center = view.center
```

you are setting `datePicker` frame according to the `view` `self.datePickerView` and adding as `subView` to it. But at the same time you are adding:

```
datePicker.center = view.center
```

according to the main view which has `self.datePickerView` as `subview`.

`datePicker` is out of the scope in that scenario.

Also your `datePicker` y frame can not be 0. It will overlap `done` and `cancel` `button`.

Answer (score 3):

This was an iOS 14 problem that I ran into and my datePicker was only peeking out from the bottom of the screen. I found the answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652943?login=true) from PetterBraka:

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePicker.sizeToFit()
}
yourTextField.inputView = datePicker
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps:

I have commented datepicker center alignment code:

```
        // DatePicker
        self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: Int(self.doneBtn.frame.origin.x) , y: Int(doneBtn.frame.origin.y + doneBtn.frame.size.height + 10), width: Int(cancelBtn.frame.origin.x + cancelBtn.frame.size.width - self.doneBtn.frame.origin.x), height: 200))
        self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        self.datePicker.layer.masksToBounds = true
//        datePicker.center = view.center
```

[image]